# Python-Opencv installation on OSX Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I've installed opencv with pip install `opencv_python`. but when i tried to import `cv2` in the interpreter,

I get this error message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from .cv2 import * ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib
>   (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib

I've installed `ffmpeg` but still get this error. How can i make thing work fine please

Comment: I've finally made it work! I've just installed `3.1.0.0` of `opencv_python`. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I first removed opencv_python using

```
pip uninstall
```

and then using conda and condo-forge

```
conda install opencv==3.1.0
```

which worked. I then did a

```
conda update opencv
```

and was updated to opencv 3.3.1 and my import of cv2 worked fine